# Почему телеграм бот отвечает только в личку?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите, почему на команду /start бот реагирует и в конфе и в лс,  но если на просто сообщение, как например тут, где он должен повторять его, он отвечает только в лс, а в конфе не отвечает. Как сделать, чтобы он и в конференции отвечал?

```
import telebot
from ilitaconfig import token_telegram

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token_telegram)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hello")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
    def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался прост. По дефолту бот не имеет доступа к сообщениям в чате. Нужно написать отцу ботов /setprivacy, дальше выбрать бота и потом Disable